# How to initialize list of lists in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

There are fifty ArrayLists that I would like to fill up. For example:

```
public static ArrayList<DictionaryElement> list1;
public static ArrayList<DictionaryElement> list2;
public static ArrayList<DictionaryElement> list3;
...
public static ArrayList<DictionaryElement> list50;
```

I fill up a list in the following manner:

```
list = getDictionary(DICT_URL);
```

Now I initialize each list separately (I mean in separate line of code). How can I do it in more automatic way?

Thanks, Michael

Comment: You could use a `List<List<DictionaryElement>>`, iterate and populate.

Comment: Why not create `ArrayList<DictionaryElement>[]` and initialze with a loop?

Comment: How about instead of having many list references use one list/array which will store your lists? You could initialize them using loop or some utility method like `Arrays.setAll`

Comment: @Maljam because generic arrays are problematic.

Comment: `list1 = list2 = list3 = ... = list50 = getDictionary(DICT_URL);` would initialize the variables *quickly*. Not really clear why speed is your primary requirement, though.

Comment: @Mena Yeah, I know I could do that, but I need every list with unique name to know what's in there.

Comment: @Pshemo Its quite good idea, but the point is to separate the objects into groups.

Comment: @Malijam I cant do that because each list requires different url (I gave example for only one list).

Comment: This smells a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) Please explain the reason you think you need to have individual variables instead of collecting the lists into a `Map<String,List<DictionaryElement>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want

```
public enum ListType { LIST1, LIST2,..... };
...
EnumMap<ListType, List<DictionaryELement>> lists = new EnumMap<>(ListType.class);
...

for (ListType t : ListType.values())
{
    lists.put(t,new ArrayList<DictionaryELement>());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for:)